# Perl one-liner repeat substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I want to repeat this search until there are no matches available in the text:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(<langSet xml.lang=....>)\s*<tig>(.*?)<\/tig>\s*<tig>/\1<tig>\2<\/tig>\1<tig>/g' iate.dsl
```

Basically, I need a while-loop in a one-liner form, which will take lines looking a bit like this

```
<langSet...><tig>...</tig><tig>...</tig><tig>...</tig><tig>...</tig>
```

and return something like this

```
<langSet...><tig>...</tig><langSet...><tig>...</tig><langSet...><tig>...</tig><langSet...><tig>...</tig>
```

where the number of `<tig>` instances varies for each line.

Comment: Uh oh. Are you sure you don't want a proper XML parser to rewrite your document? Using regular expressions is asking for disaster.

Comment: Well, I already know some stuff about regular expressions and nothing about XML parsers, so...

Comment: Seriously...  what @tadman said.  There is no shame in not knowing, but in the category of "the right tool for the right job" it's well worth your time to  check it out.

Comment: Re ask the question and frame it as an XML parsing problem, and you will get some useful answers. Regex parsing XML creates brittle code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(<langSet xml.lang=....>)\s*<tig>(.*?)<\/tig>\s*<tig>/\1<tig>\2<\/tig>\1<tig>/g while m/(<langSet xml.lang=....>)\s*<tig>(.*?)<\/tig>\s*<tig>/gi' iate.dsl
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first this is not a "search", this is a "substitution" and the second think is, that you don't need a while loop, cause the 'perl one liner' read out every single row.

But you can use an "if-statement" like -> 's/foo/bar/i if m/foo/i' or similar thinks, like ternare if-then-else but, it is not necessary. I would make a check first with the flag "-p" without "-i" (not  "-pi"), to check the output first.

example:

```
 perl -p -e 's/(<langSet xml.lang=....>)\s*<tig>(.*?)<\/tig>\s*<tig>/\1<tig>
\2<\/tig>\1<tig>/g if m/(<langSet xml.lang=....>)\s*<tig>(.*?)<\/tig>
\s*<tig>/gi' iate.dsl
```

Good luck.

Comment: I used your solution but with a "while" instead of an "if", and it works. (The "if" statement only makes the substitution once.

Comment: Hi, i believe that actually the "if" or "while" statement are redundant in your case, maybe it just is useful for a better performance by really many rows. You could make some check without this statements, with probably same results like before, cause your one-row-statement already is a loop throw every single row and actually the regex definition decide if you substitute every "match" or just one of it and so on. But the main think is, that it works. Cheers.